# NumPy - Map array of labels into binary array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array of labels that represents numbers from 0-9. I'd like to transform this array into a binary array such that the number is the index of the value = 1.

Example:

```
labels = [1, 4, 9]
binary = [
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
]
```

I already have an iterative solution but I'm looking for a NumPy solution.

Answer (score 3):

A simple and quick way:

```
>>> labels = [1, 4, 9]
>>> np.eye(10, dtype=int)[labels]
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```